# How to authenticate ejabberd with django?

Tags: python, django, ejabberd

**Problem Statement**

I have a normal django model

**Models.py**

```
class Fan(models.Model):
    user_id = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=250)
    ...
    ...
```

**Question 1**

> How do i authenticate ejabberd JID against this `user_id`?

**Question 2**

> Which xmpp client (android and web) supports external ejabberd authentication?

**My Approach**

As per the doc i made the following changes in,

**ejabberd.yml**

```
auth_method: external
extauth_program: "/home/niranj/Documents/entry.sh"
```

**entry.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash 

workon orchestrator
/usr/bin/python /home/niranj/Documents/work.py $@
```

**work.py**

```
import sys
print sys.argv
```

> Please note that i have provided ejabberd permission to access the files above

I always get the following error in **ejabberd.log**

```
2016-05-18 15:13:11.202 [critical] <0.411.0>@extauth:loop:142 extauth script has exitted abruptly with reason 'normal'
```

**Question 3**

> How do i solve this error? Anything wrong in this configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out the solution for **question 3**,

**work.py**

```
import sys

while True:
    print sys.argv
```

Need to make the loop as infinite loop this is the key here.

As this is fixed my **question 1** is also fixed which is obvious.